# How do I change shortcut keys with autohotkey? Change "lang" key to the right alt

Tags: autohotkey

Hi I have a little problem with the keyboard :

https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.1ca6faaa87fdfeadac2dccd3dcf6e79d?rik=Am9uvhyXc8DinA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fimages.samsung.com%2fis%2fimage%2fsamsung%2fde-universal-bluetooth-keyboard-bt230-ej-bt230mwegde-000061123-front-white%3f%24PD_GALLERY_JPG%24&ehk=9L5Gwm4P0CKfrx8nWx%2bnDKRKP4tTKafA2Svo2o9A%2bGY%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0
[image]

I want to change the "lang" button to the right alt.

My code works fine but it types a capital letter (probably by shift). Can you help me?

Comment: Try to find out the [scan code](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) of the key and remap it in your script e.g. `SC159::RAlt`.

Comment: Could you add your code so we see what you have already tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example